# How to lock table fields in Emacs Org-Mode (make them read only, constant)?

Tags: emacs, spreadsheet, org-mode, readonly

I'm working on a spreadsheet for a wargaming game. Some fields have
constant values defining points values of a single model and I want to
make these fields read only/constant (to not modify them
accidentally). Here's a demonstration list in an Org-Mode, with two
units of Skeletons (16 and 24 models) and two of Bone Dragons (1 and 2
models), both with upgrades (additional values to sum up):

```
#+CONSTANTS: SKELETON=6 SKELETON_BOW=2 SKELETON_SWORD=1
#+CONSTANTS: BONE_DRAGON=60 BONE_DRAGON_POISON=20
|---+-------------+------+------+-----+----+-----|
|   | _UNIT_      | P[1] | N[2] |   + |  N |   + |
|---+-------------+------+------+-----+----+-----|
| # | SKELETON    |    6 |   16 |  96 | 24 | 144 |
| # | Bow         |    2 |    0 |   0 | 12 |  24 |
| # | Sword       |    1 |   16 |  16 | 12 |  12 |
| # | *SUMS*      |      |      | 112 |    | 180 |
| # | *TOTAL*     |  292 |      |     |    |     |
|---+-------------+------+------+-----+----+-----|
| # | BONE_DRAGON |   80 |    1 |  80 |  2 | 160 |
| # | Poison      |   20 |    1 |  20 |  0 |   0 |
| # | *SUMS*      |      |      | 100 |    | 160 |
| # | *TOTAL*     |  260 |      |     |    |     |
|---+-------------+------+------+-----+----+-----|
| # | *TOTAL*     |  552 |      |     |    |     |
|---+-------------+------+------+-----+----+-----|
#+TBLFM: @2$3=$SKELETON::@2$5=(@2$3*@2$4)::@2$7=(@2$3*@2$6)::@3$3=$SKELETON_BOW::@3$5=(@3$3*@3$4)::@3$7=(@3$3*@3$6)::@4$3=$SKELETON_SWORD::@4$5=(@4$3*@4$4)::@4$7=(@4$3*@4$6)::@5$5=vsum(@2$5..@4$5)::@5$7=vsum(@2$7..@4$7)::@6$3=(@5$5+@5$7)::@7$3=$BONE_DRAGON::@7$5=(@7$3*@7$4)::@7$7=(@7$3*@7$6)::@8$3=$BONE_DRAGON_POISON::@8$5=(@8$3*@8$4)::@8$7=(@8$3*@8$6)::@9$5=vsum(@7$5..@8$5)::@9$7=vsum(@7$7..@8$7)::@10$3=(@9$5+@9$7)::@11$3=(@6$3+@10$3)

[1] Points per model
[2] Number of models
```

As You can see, I've reached a solution with constants (constant.el
package by Carsten Dominik
http://staff.science.uva.nl/~dominik/Tools/).

What has been achieved:

- accidental modification of PPM is restored
- constants are defined only once

**Is there a standard Org-Mode way to make fields really read only?** I
haven't found an answer in an Org-Mode Manual.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the org-mode way, but ["Emacs: make portion of buffer readonly"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76531/emacs-make-portion-of-buffer-readonly) might help.  What it does is to set a read-only property in a buffer with put-text-property.

Comment: Thanks for the link, 'make-region-read-only' method is very handy :).
Unfortunately it does not work with Org Mode tables, making them
impossible to edit.